# React, accessing a var from a script in a component

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs

I have been trying to import an external library (google Maps) in order to use it in a React component

**index.html** file

```
<div id="app"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY_GOES_HERE&callback=initMap" async defer>
```

**react file**

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.refs.map, {
      center: {lat: this.props.lat, lng: this.props.lng},
      zoom: 8
    });   
  }

    render() {
      return <div>
        <p>I am a map component</p>
        <div id="map" ref="map"/>
      </div>
    }
```

The error I get is:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined

I have tried everything but nothing seems to be working. How do I access the variable from this script inside my component?

This is just an example, please do not tell me to use one of the NPM packages for React Google Maps.

Thanks,
Harris

Comment: Try moving the google <script> include above your app javascript file and load it synchronously. This isn't the best way, but should fix your problem if you don't want to use the NPM package

Comment: Did you load your component before importing google map api ?

Comment: @TMitchell I tried your solution even inside the head and body but same error occurs.

Comment: Do you use webpack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because the google api is not loaded before your React Component is loading.

Place the script tag for google in the header, before loading your react scripts.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY_GOES_HERE&callback=initMap" async defer>

    <!-- React scripts here -->
</head>
```

If you're still having trouble, try adding a `debugger;` line in `didComponentMount()` function and check in the console if `google` is loaded and available.

Comment: Can you post your whole html file?
Should be in this order:
- Google script in head, then:
- React lib script in head, then:
- In body, `div#app`, then:
- App JS file end of body

Comment: I don't know how this didn't work earlier but this time it did work. Thank you very much

Comment: @Eristikos perhaps the script is now cached and loading quicker. I would suggest removing the async attribute, there's a possible race condition here

Answer (score 12):

A little late to the party but I also had this issue and for me it was caused by eslint. To disable it just add the comment     `/*global google*/` above where you declare the variable and it should work e.g.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    /*global google*/ // To disable any eslint 'google not defined' errors
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.refs.map, {
      center: {lat: this.props.lat, lng: this.props.lng},
      zoom: 8
    });   
  }

    render() {
      return <div>
        <p>I am a map component</p>
        <div id="map" ref="map"/>
      </div>
    }
```

You can also use the window object to make the call:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    /* Use new window.google... instead of new google... */
    this.map = new window.google.maps.Map(this.refs.map, {
      center: {lat: this.props.lat, lng: this.props.lng},
      zoom: 8
    });   
  }

    render() {
      return <div>
        <p>I am a map component</p>
        <div id="map" ref="map"/>
      </div>
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

In general you can import a script with the following:

```
let aScript = document.createElement('script');
aScript.type = 'text/javascript';
aScript.src = "link to script";
document.head.appendChild(aScript);
```

NOTE: Before you can use the variable, the script has to load in!

After the script is loaded you can use a variable from the script with

```
window.variable
```

(in this case)

```
window.google.maps.whatever
```

If you want to use a variable directly after a script is imported (on page load etc) you can do something like this:

```
let aScript = document.createElement('script');
aScript.type = 'text/javascript';
aScript.src = "link to script";

document.head.appendChild(aScript);

aScript.onload = function() {
    window.variableFromScript.whatever
}
```

Comment: window.google did the trick for me // I placed the <script> in my html header